# Set upper and lower bytes of an (short int) in C++

Tags: c++, integer, typeconverter

i have problem for setting upper and lower bytes of (short int).
please look on my code it just return number 1 but must return 55 .

```
int number = 55;
int mynumber = 0;

//convert short int to char.
char upper = number >> 8;
char lower = number && 8;

//convert char to short int .
mynumber = (mynumber & 0xff00) | lower;
mynumber = (mynumber & 0x00ff) | (upper << 8);

printf("%i",mynumber);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spliting an hex into 2 hex values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811662/spliting-an-hex-into-2-hex-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lower` calculation is wrong:

```
char lower = number & 0xff;
```